# Maven installation of guvnor can't find ResourceType variable

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, drools, drools-guvnor

I'm trying to install drools guvnor on an Ubuntu system with `mvn clean install -DskipTests`, and I'm receiving an error output like this:

```
[INFO] 39 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Guvnor multiproject ............................... SUCCESS [1.539s]
[INFO] kie-uberfire-bootstrap ............................ SUCCESS [5.865s]
[INFO] kie-project-editor ................................ SUCCESS [6.465s]
[INFO] Guvnor API ........................................ SUCCESS [1.993s]
[INFO] Guvnor repository connector multiproject .......... SUCCESS [0.056s]
[INFO] Guvnor repository connector JCR ................... SUCCESS [1.463s]
[INFO] Guvnor repository connector Jackrabbit ............ SUCCESS [1.920s]
[INFO] Guvnor repository connector ModeShape ............. SUCCESS [1.827s]
[INFO] Guvnor repository ................................. SUCCESS [8.587s]
[INFO] Drools and jBPM IDE common ........................ FAILURE [11.337s]
[INFO] Guvnor web application core ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Guvnor web application Drools ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Guvnor bulk importer .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Guvnor JCR to UberFire VFS migration .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Guvnor examples ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 43.425s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Dec 06 22:13:58 EET 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 32M/78M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project droolsjbpm-ide-common: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
[ERROR] SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
[ERROR] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[ERROR] /home/neyo/drools/guvnor/droolsjbpm-ide-common/src/test/java/org/drools/ide/common/server/factconstraints/predefined/RangeConstraintMultipleOperatorsTest.java:[37,22] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class ResourceType
[ERROR] location: package org.kie.builder
[ERROR] /home/neyo/drools/guvnor/droolsjbpm-ide-common/src/test/java/org/drools/ide/common/server/factconstraints/predefined/RangeConstraintSingleOperatorTest.java:[38,22] error: cannot find symbol
[...]
[ERROR] symbol:   variable ResourceType
[ERROR] location: class MandatoryFieldConstraintTest
[ERROR] /home/neyo/drools/guvnor/droolsjbpm-ide-common/src/test/java/org/drools/ide/common/server/factconstraints/predefined/NotMatchesConstraintTest.java:[148,124] error: cannot find symbol
[...]
```

Any thoughts why it can't find `ResourceType` ?

I'm using maven 3.0.4 and java 1.7, and I've cloned all the repositories from github.com/droolsjbpm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem, and I'm seeing a possibly related [commit](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/commit/73cee9a551da1aff9f5488f100f2386f72661472#jbpm-gwt/jbpm-gwt-graph/src/main/java/org/jbpm/integration/console/graph/GraphViewerPluginImpl.java) on a file from their github repository:

```
-import org.kie.builder.ResourceType;
+import org.kie.io.ResourceType;
```

So they possibly changed their packages around a bit. Try changing that inside the files see if it fixes it, I will verify tonight when I can.

Comment: Seems like they already updated the guvnor repo on git as well with those changes, thanks.